# Material Design 3 - Default text sizes for TopAppBars

Tags: android, material-design

What default text sizes are used for the `CenterAlignedTopAppBar`, `SmallTopAppBar`, `MediumTopAppBar` and `LargeTopAppBar` in Material Design 3? Are these sizes specified in `dp` or `sp`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of all the styles and their defaults [here](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/typography-theming):

- textAppearanceTitleLarge: *Regular 22sp*
- textAppearanceHeadlineSmall: *Regular 24sp*
- textAppearanceHeadlineMedium: *Regular 28sp*

Outside of specific situations where you want a fixed, consistent size, text size is always defined in *sp* so it can scale to the user's preferences, and maintain the size relationship between different types of text

Answer (score 1):

App bar and their height

```
LargeTopAppBar -> 152.0.dp
MediumTopAppBar -> 112.0.dp
SmallTopAppBar -> 64.0.dp
CenterAlignedTopAppBar -> 64.0.dp
```

**Source:**
`TopAppBarSmallTokens.kt`, `TopAppBarMediumTokens.kt` and `TopAppBarLargeTokens.kt` source code.